# How to vertically list days of the month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following imagr. What this basically represents is a rota. What I am trying to do is implement this into a system that I am building using Ruby On Rails. However I have identified that my first thing to do is list the dates of the month vertically. Which I am somewhat a bit confused by. Horizontally the headers represents different hospitals. Against the days and hospitals are names which shows who is working at what hospital. The colour coding is not relevant now.

The horizontal headings are the hospital. These are a fixed value of 10 hospitals. What I am finding difficult is to generate the current day which in my image uses the current day as the 16th and goes up to the 12th of may.

I have attempted to come up with some pseudo code, but am not too sure if I am heading in the right direction with this

`(Date.today..23.days.from_now).each do |d|; td= d.to_s(:short);`

Though I was thinking that maybe encasing the  inside the loop would automatically generate the cells for me alongside with the dates

Is there a possible solution to achieveing what I am trying to do.

My models are as followed:

- Department
- Hospital_booking
- Hospital
- role_user
- role
- rota_day
- user

Another thing that came to mind is that because I know that there is a fixed value of hospitals which is 10. I was thinking that maybe I could do something as followed:

```
<table class="rota">
        <thead>
            <th> Dates </th>
                     <th> Hospital </th>
            <% end %>
        </thead>
        <% @Hospital.each do |Hospital| %>
            <tr class="rota_days" id="rota_days<%= hospital_id %>">
```

This way it could loop through the hospitals and generate the headers however I will be still stuck in generating the dates

Comment: Can you talk a bit about what your models are in the Rails system? Are they hospitals? Employees? Departments? Once you have a model of your data it should be easy to feed the appropriate data to the view.

Comment: I will update my question further with the more information. Give me  a few minutes

Comment: How are you determining what days a person is working at what hospital? Is this stored in the hospital model? or in a user model with a reference to a rota_day?

Comment: This is stored in hospital_bookings. Hospital_bookings belongs to hospital. So yes I am storing them in the hospital model. Here is a link of all my models. http://pastebin.com/W6AurQyn

Comment: This seems to be a 100% server-side (Ruby on Rails) question. Do the javascript and jQuery tags indicate that you are looking for a client-side aspect to the solution? And if so, why?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot included the javascript and jQuery tags as I had been looking at some javascript solutions to doing this. Further to this I had also looked at jQuery event calendar and thought that maybe this could be changed so it matches what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Djj, it might be a good idea to explain those aspects in the question.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for the reply I will remove the tags from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are kind of on the right track, but am not 100% sure on where you are having issues.

To solve this I would pass the view `@hospitals` and `@days` which correspond to which hospitals you want to list and which days you want to be listed. The `get_hospital_booking_for_day` would be a view helper you make that either returns the name of the person on duty or a `nbsp;` so that the blank cells display correctly.

Again, I'm not sure this is 100% correct for you but hopefully it will put you on the right track:

```
<table class="rota">
    <thead>
    <% @hospitals.each do |hosp| %>
        <th><%= hosp.name %></th>
    <% end %>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @days.each do |day| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= day.to_s(:short) %></td>
            <% @hospitals.each do |hosp| %>
                <td><%= get_hospital_booking_for_day(hosp, day) %></td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just had a read of this and it looks like its defiantly something I could attempt to work off of. I will pursue this further. :-)

Comment: Nice work james I went to get some coffee and you beat me too it I like your solution way better

Comment: I understnad that `<% @days.each do |day| %>` is to loop around the day. I am guessing I will need to create a model and controller to handle this, that has a day attribute that has a type `t.date`?

Comment: @Djj - @days is just an instance variable that you set in the controller that loads the current view. I don't know how your `rota_day` model is structured, but just building an array of those may suffice.

Comment: Further to my previous comment - If I wanted to just get a date range could I not just do create a range to iterate through it and do something like e.g. Date.today..(Date.today + 18.days) if you want dates from today to the next 18 days

Comment: @Djj - Yes, you could. As long as you have a way of lining those 'Rails days' up with your 'rota days' then there is no problem doing it that way. Generally, it is considered bad practice to do any sort of logic in the view. So usually you would populate an instance variable with the information needed by the view (which is the way I coded it up). Don't let that stop you though, do it however you feel comfortable.

Comment: Regarding the code you posted, you are setting `@days` to `RotaDay.all` but then you overwrite that value with `@days = []`. Remove that second assignment and see if it behaves as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Listing the months vertically is an illusion created by the view. The easiest way to do it is to have a data field like

> month, 1, 3, john

and putting it inside of a json object as so. (***NOTE***: Got some other method in JS? go ahead - your formatting issue is discussed right after anyways). I'm going to use an array.

```
var outputs = [];
for (i = 0; i < amountOfOutputs; i++) {
     outputs[i] = { month: "",
                    datafield1: "",
                    datafield2: "",
                    datafield3: "" }
}
```

And then I would append the objects to your table (if you have to use tables...). And the answer to your question is exposed here.

```
for (i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++ ) {
    var $row =     $('<tr class="'+i+'">').
    var $month =   $('<td>').text(outputs[i].month);
    var $df1 =     $('<td>').text(outputs[i].datafield1);
    var $df2 =     $('<td>').text(outputs[i].datafield2);
    var $df3 =     $('<td>').text(outputs[i].datafield3);
    $row.appendTo('table');
    $month.appendTo('tr.'+i+'');
    $df1.appendTo('tr.'+i+'');
    $df2.appendTo('tr.'+i+'');
    $df3.appendTo('tr.'+i+'');
}
```

And you should have your table with the months displayed vertically.

I hope this helps, let me know if I wasn't close to the solution and I'll try again. Its not an 100% complete solution but it should be you on the right track for **formatting**.